# AMP CLIENT_ID substitution not working

Tags: amp-html

Following [AMP HTML URL Variable Substitutions](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md) I have added an amp-pixel with `CLIENT_ID(google-analytics)`. I would expect empty string as it isn't on the AMP CDN and the cookie doesn't exist. However the text remains `CLIENT_ID(google-analytics)` in the url. `RANDOM` is substituted.

full amp-pixel :

`amp-pixel src="//www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-23688336-7&cid=CLIENT_ID(google-analytics)&t=pageview&dp=%2fnews%2f2016-01-05%2fjekyll-and-hyde-axed-by-itv%2famp&cd1=Visitor&cd2=Popular%20channels&cd4=Sci-fi%2CDrama&cd6=Charlie-Higson&cd7=Jekyll-and-Hyde&cd10=AMP&z=RANDOM"`

Can anyone see anything wrong or advise please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `cid scope`. You may review the required and optional arguments you may pass into CLIENT_ID like a function.

> Be noted that spaces between arguments and values are not allowed.

- `cid scope` (Required) - Name of the fallback cookie when the document is not served by an AMP proxy.
- `amp-user-notification id` (Optional) - Optionally make the CLIENT_ID substitution be dependent on the dismissal of a user notification shown to the visitor of the page.

Check this [example](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/a5791f1b8337aab23618e68fa40e3d4445f67651/examples/user-notification.amp.html).

Comment: I am using cid=CLIENT_ID(google-analytics) as in the AMP examples. I'm expecting to see a cookie in this case 'google-analytics' as the fallback.